# Selection of DC-DC converter for boosting 4.2V to 5.0V

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I need to boost 4.2V (out of MPPT/ 18650 battery charge) to 5V (input for ESP8266.) To accomplish that I've bought [this item](https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-DC-Step-Up-Converter-MT3608-Booster-Power-Supply-Module-Boost-Step-up/303338666843?hash=item46a064bb5b:g:6qQAAOSwZM1dtrDI), a 2.0 - 24V boost converter, which supports 2A.

But when trying to do so - though voltage is converted as needed and does not drop during boot - the MCU does not power up.

I tried to add 100 microfarad capacitor at input and output of the converter. No luck.

1. Is there a way to "fix" this converter to power an MCU?
2. If not, what type of converter would be suited for the job?

Comment: An ESP8266 runs off 3.3V - why do you need 5V?

Comment: I rather use microUSB port (5v regulated - for more power stability)

Comment: [ESP8266EX datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf) page 23 indicates maximum voltage is 3.6. It's likely that it won't boot because it's damaged from overvoltage.

Comment: @JYelton - 5v via USB

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. 5V is 5V, whether it is from USB or not. If you want to power the ESP8266 from USB, then you need a _buck_ converter to lower the voltage to an acceptable value.

Comment: I was understood wrong. 4.2v is supplied by 18650 battery. i need boost converter tp 5v ( so there no problem with voltage greater that 3.6v as you wrote earlier ).

Comment: @JYelton:  Many (most, all?) ESP8266 modules have a USB port and accept 5V.  They have a 3.3V regulator on board, but you can also feed them 3.3V.

Comment: @JRE Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: maybe a brown-out-detector / power-on reset circuit is needed.

Comment: @Jasen can you explain more?

Comment: some processors have trouble starting if the spply voltage is unstable or too slowly rising

Comment: @Jasen - this I agree, and tried adding capacitors in order to stabilize voltageq current